# Mongodb get the 3-byte counter from an ObjectId

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, objectid

How/Can I get the

> 3-byte counter, starting with a random value

part from a mongodb ObjectId?

I have an ObjectId like this:
ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011")

According to mongodb documentation:

> Description
>
> ObjectId() Returns a new ObjectId value. The 12-byte
> ObjectId value consists of:

a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,

a 3-byte machine identifier,

a 2-byte process id,

**and a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.**

I want to get the "**and a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.**" part from the ObjectId above if its possible.

Comment: can u elaborate your question please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try the following hack where you can get the equivalent string representation of the **[`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)** using **[`toString()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html)** or **`toHexString()`**, use `parseInt` and `slice` to get the parts. Because hex digits are half of a byte the offsets are twice as much:

```
db.collection("collectionName").findOne({}, function(err, result) {     
    if (result) {
        var id          = result._id.toString(), ctr = 0;
        var timestamp   = parseInt(id.slice(ctr, (ctr+=8)), 16);
        var machineID   = parseInt(id.slice(ctr, (ctr+=6)), 16);
        var processID   = parseInt(id.slice(ctr, (ctr+=4)), 16);
        var counter     = parseInt(id.slice(ctr, (ctr+=6)), 16);
        console.log(id);
        console.log(timestamp);
        console.log(machineID);
        console.log(processID);
        console.log(counter);                    
    }       
});
```

Comment: tested with "507f1f77bcf86cd799439011" here are the results:
timestamp: 1350508407,
machineId: 12384364,
processID: 55193,
counter: 4427793

These are all good but timestamp 1350508407 does not look ok.
new Date(1350508407) = Fri Jan 16 1970 16:08:28 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)

Comment: Timestamp is not in milliseconds, you need to multiply by 1000 first to get the actual date i.e. `new Date(1350508407*1000) = Wed Oct 17 2012 22:13:27 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)`

Comment: on what basis the documents are sorted? I see all information identical for data inserted in bulk.

Comment: I'm using this for the counter and I'm seeing duplicate counters for different ID's. Is it supposed to be unique?