# Find a document by INC value in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

From my website client I am sending an API request to the backend Node.js server and finding a specific document by ID like so:

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;   

db.collection('users').find({"_id": new ObjectID(req.body._id)})
```

Where **req.body._id** equals the entire ID string, such as *'5d0381ad681a2a3aa1dc5872'*

However I would prefer to send only the **INC** (ever incrementing value) portion of the string as the argument: *'c5872'*

How should I find a specific document based on just the INC value? (I'm assuming the INC is unique)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018036

Comment: Hi, there is not guarantee the INC will be unique. Why concern about using the ObjectId?

Comment: It's just to keep it simple and clean. We provide the ID as a URL parameter to our affiliates, and we prefer using 5 characters as opposed to 24

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can temporarily transform your _id using in a string to be able to use a regular expression :

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: { id: { $toString: '$_id' } }
  },
  {
    $match: { id: /c5872$/ }
  }
])
```

A cleaner solution is to create the field directly with a substring to avoid using a regular expression :

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: { id: { $substr: [{ $toString: '$_id' }, 19, 24] } }
  },
  {
    $match: { id: 'c5872' }
  }
])
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/

Comment: Hi, it does look clean, in the other hand the documentation said: Place the `$match` as early in the aggregation pipeline as possible. Because `$match` limits the total number of documents in the aggregation pipeline, earlier `$match` operations minimize the amount of processing down the pipe.

Comment: @HanielBaez Yes, the `$addFields` operation will be done on the entire collection but this needs to be done before applying the `$match`. If the collection is large, it is preferable to really create the field in the database in order to have an index on the field, as you suggested in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an additional ID field and a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) to ensure that indexed fields do not store duplicate values, but note that for a five hex string, we have "1,048,576" possible combinations (16 ^ 5 = 1048576).

Note: Using a regular expression could lead to a collection scan.

> A regular expression is a "prefix expression" if it starts with a
> caret (^) or a left anchor (\A), followed by a string of simple
> symbols. For example, the regex /^abc.*/ will be optimized by matching
> only against the values from the index that start with abc.

[Regular expression and index use](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use)

Comment: Using 6 characters instead of 5 is fine for me.

Comment: Isn't the _id field automatically generated by MongoDB already unique? Or are you suggesting creating an additional ID field in order to avoid a collection scan?

Comment: Yes, the _id is unique. What I said is that, you should be caution when using regex, it can lent to a collection scan.

Comment: But it will only lead to a collection scan if no value stored in MongoDB can satisfy the query. But in that case even if I create an additional ID field (no regex) I run the risk of a collection scan correct?

Comment: Hmmm... I think I understand what you mean. By creating an additional ID field we can put an index on that field. Thus avoiding the potential for a collection scan

Comment: If the field is indexed, and not value can satisfy the query, the worst thing that could happen, is an index scan (not that bad).